# How do you solve $ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2-2n-4}{n^4+4n^2+16}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2-2n-4}{n^4+4n^2+16}$$

Having tried similar questions before, I could factorize it upto

$$ \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n^2-2n-4}{(n^2+2n+4)(n^2-2n+4)}$$

But after this point, I'm having trouble expressing it as a difference between two terms

Comment: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h2556461p21879209 I found it by [Approach Zero's search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bi%3D2%7D%5E%5Cinfty%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%5E2-2n-4%7D%7Bn%5E4%2B4n%5E2%2B16%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: It should be: $n =2$, not $i = 2$ ?

Comment: Ahh, thanks guys!